# Show users a view of nodes tagged with the terms they flagged - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, flags

I want users to be able to create taxonomy terms and other users to be able to flag these taxonomy terms (using the flag module, sort of Follow). Then i want each user to have a view of nodes which have been tagged with those taxonomy terms they flagged. Is this currently possible with views contextual filters? Any alternative also welcome.

Example use case: i flagged terms Technology and Business created by admin or other users. When a user posts a node tagged with Technology or Business, i will see the post on my wall (My wall is an admin created view of all nodes tagged with the terms that i have flagged)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this can be done:

1. In the View, add a Relationship to the node's taxonomy term (using  "Content: Taxonomy terms on node")
2. Either add a filter criteria for the term, or add a contextual filter that would limit the terms to those flagged by the particular user.